# Disable ability go back to previous activity

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity

When switching to the `MainActivity` from `OnboardingSetupActivity` i can pressed back and go back in `OnboardingSetupActivity`.

```
override fun showMainActivity() {
        startActivity(Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
            .apply { putExtra(KEY_SKIP_PIN, true) }
            .apply { flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK })
    }
```

Q: Why? How to disable the ability go back to `OnboardingSetupActivity`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will clear back task of application and when you press back button application will close. You need to add flags in Intent or you can use `finish()`.

```
val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
startActivity(intent)
finish()
```

Comment: if i call `finish()` before `startActivity(intent)` it will be better?

Comment: Why u think so?

Answer (score 0):

**Why?**

it's because by default when you click back button your activity calls `super.onBackPressed()` method.

**How to disable?**

override `onBackPressed()` and remove `super.onBackPressed()` from it

```
  @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed(); // remove or comment this line
}
```